# Yahoo Pipes - Remove a specific item

Tags: xml, rss, yahoo-pipes

My Pipe:
https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=1adf6172dc093c321af04aa4864af0ee

So, what I want is this: 
if item.title == "Sticky" then delete this result,

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Filter module from Operators to do that.